# Populate the name of locations based on user's input

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a weather app in which users can add other locations to view weather information for. Right now what I have implemented is let the user finish entering the location name and once its done I check whether the location exists(use it to get weather info for the location, if weather info exists, location exists). This works fine but I have seen in other apps where they populate a uitableview based on the users input.

Which api and how are they doing it so fast? I mean the first letter I type example 'A', it takes a while to populate the uitableview but every other alphabet after that reveals instant change in data for the uitableview.

I would like to implement this into my app. I tried googling but I can't seem to find the right keywords. LOL. I got the google-maps-sdk but is'nt that an overkill? All I want are names.

Answer (score 0):

i'm a personal fan of google maps sdk. the speed with which they return results is lightning fast. if you do [TableView reloadData], upon getting every response from google, you should see instant results.Yes, it's that fast :)
However, there could be one thing to speed up the above process even further. You could cache the previously fetched results locally into a db or plist on the device. When the user searches for a particular text, first look into local storage, try to filter that stored result by matching the new search text. Display this result , else if no results were found locally, hit the google server. Or you could club both local results and google results. first update the tableview with local results and then reload when google gives results.